# Scraping Data from Tutiempo

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape solar radiation data from Tutiempo and I am having a super tough time figuring this out. I am relatively new to coding and have been at this for roughly a week now. The data is in a weird format that I've never worked with before so I was hoping to get some help!

The code I have so far is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website to scrape
url = "https://en.tutiempo.net/solar-radiation/lethbridge.html"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the div that contains the solar radiation data
solar_radiation_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="horashidsow ocultas")

# Extract the solar radiation data from each hourly sub-div
for solar_radiation_divs in solar_radiation_div:
    # Extract the hour from the sub-div's ID
    hour = solar_radiation_div["id"].split("-")[1]
    
    # Extract the solar radiation data from the span
    solar_radiation = solar_radiation_div.find("span", class_="ener").text
    
    print(f"Hour {hour}: {solar_radiation} W/m²")
    
    data.append(solar_radiation)
```

The code results in a list of divs with the data but I'm unable to iterate over them as I would like to,

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, then you can't iterate on the result. For your program to work correctly, you need to call the "find_all" method again for each day, and then find the time and radiation level tags. For clarity, you can still extract the day of the week. Here is the working code, I hope this is what you were looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website to scrape
url = "https://en.tutiempo.net/solar-radiation/lethbridge.html"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the div that contains the solar radiation data
# solar_radiation_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="horashidsow")
solar_radiation_divs = soup.find("div", class_="RadiacionSolar mt10")
data=list()

# Extract the solar radiation data from each hourly sub-div
for solar_radiation_div in solar_radiation_divs:
    hours = solar_radiation_div.find_all("div", "horhor")

    # Extract the day
    try:
        day = solar_radiation_div.find('h3').text
        print(day)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    for hour in hours:
        # Extract the hour
        time = hour.find("span", "hora").text
        
        # Extract the solar radiation data from the span
        solar_radiation = hour.find("span", "ener").text
        
        print(f"Hour {time}: {solar_radiation} W/m²")
        
        data.append(solar_radiation)
```

The result in the console:

```
Today - 10 May
Hour 07:00: 107 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 08:00: 258 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 09:00: 414 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 10:00: 557 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 11:00: 681 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 12:00: 757 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 13:00: 767 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 14:00: 769 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 15:00: 741 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 16:00: 651 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 17:00: 540 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 18:00: 401 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 19:00: 245 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 20:00: 96 w/m2 W/m²
Tomorrow - 11 May
Hour 07:00: 72 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 08:00: 167 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 09:00: 264 w/m2 W/m²
Hour 10:00: 374 w/m2 W/m²
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data in a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), this way :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

dias = [div.get("id") for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "enedia"})]

data = []
for i in range(1, len(dias)+1):
    day_div = soup.find("div", {"id": f"ResDia{i}"})
    date = day_div.find("h3").text.strip()
    total_radiation = day_div.find("span", {"class": "tot"}).find("strong").text.strip()
    hours_data = [(hour_div.find("span", {"class": "hora"}).text.strip(),
                   hour_div.find("span", {"class": "ener"}).find("strong").text.strip())
                  for hour_div in soup.find(
                     "div", {"id": f"HorasDia{i}"}).find_all("div", {"class": "horhor"})
    ]

    for hour, radiation in hours_data:
        data.append(
            {"date": date,
             "total_radiation": total_radiation,
             "hour": hour,
             "radiation": radiation}
        )

df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
          .pivot(index=["date", "total_radiation"], columns="hour", values="radiation")
          .reset_index(level=1).rename_axis(columns=None).astype("Int64")
          .sort_index(key= lambda x: x.str.split(" - ").str[-1])
)
```

Output :

| date | total_radiation | 06:00 | 07:00 | 08:00 | 09:00 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 13:00 | 14:00 | 15:00 | 16:00 | 17:00 | 18:00 | 19:00 | 20:00 | 21:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Today - 10 May | 6984 |  | 107 | 258 | 414 | 557 | 681 | 757 | 767 | 769 | 741 | 651 | 540 | 401 | 245 | 96 |  |
| Tomorrow - 11 May | 4999 |  | 72 | 167 | 264 | 374 | 485 | 569 | 242 | 298 | 548 | 630 | 553 | 425 | 256 | 116 |  |
| Friday - 12 May | 7373 |  | 130 | 289 | 442 | 579 | 691 | 769 | 809 | 808 | 765 | 685 | 572 | 433 | 280 | 121 |  |
| Saturday - 13 May | 7405 |  | 133 | 290 | 444 | 582 | 693 | 771 | 811 | 810 | 767 | 687 | 574 | 436 | 283 | 124 |  |
| Sunday - 14 May | 6999 |  | 103 | 258 | 414 | 543 | 649 | 584 | 755 | 805 | 770 | 689 | 577 | 439 | 286 | 127 |  |
| Monday - 15 May | 7482 |  | 139 | 298 | 450 | 587 | 698 | 776 | 815 | 814 | 772 | 692 | 579 | 442 | 289 | 131 |  |
| Tuesday - 16 May | 7309 |  | 107 | 240 | 374 | 562 | 697 | 778 | 817 | 816 | 774 | 694 | 581 | 444 | 291 | 134 |  |
| Wednesday - 17 May | 7546 |  | 145 | 303 | 455 | 591 | 702 | 780 | 819 | 818 | 776 | 696 | 584 | 447 | 294 | 136 |  |
| Thursday - 18 May | 7178 |  | 136 | 303 | 458 | 593 | 704 | 782 | 821 | 820 | 778 | 692 | 539 | 317 | 174 | 61 |  |
| Friday - 19 May | 7469 |  | 122 | 283 | 447 | 590 | 705 | 784 | 823 | 822 | 780 | 694 | 544 | 439 | 295 | 141 |  |
| Saturday - 20 May | 5467 | 1 | 151 | 301 | 439 | 549 | 620 | 642 | 641 | 592 | 507 | 399 | 281 | 168 | 119 | 57 |  |
| Sunday - 21 May | 7120 | 1 | 91 | 232 | 392 | 548 | 682 | 775 | 808 | 798 | 751 | 664 | 548 | 412 | 280 | 138 |  |
| Monday - 22 May | 7147 | 6 | 158 | 315 | 466 | 601 | 712 | 789 | 828 | 820 | 760 | 645 | 481 | 298 | 185 | 83 |  |
| Tuesday - 23 May | 1934 | 2 | 40 | 79 | 117 | 151 | 178 | 198 | 208 | 207 | 197 | 177 | 149 | 115 | 77 | 38 | 1 |
| Wednesday - 24 May | 1945 | 3 | 41 | 80 | 118 | 151 | 179 | 198 | 208 | 208 | 197 | 178 | 150 | 116 | 78 | 39 | 1 |